# How prioritize between conservation of angular momentum and the equipartition theorem?

Tags: thermodynamics, conservation-laws, gas

In most or all description of gas equilibrium the equipartition theorem is used to motivate that energy is equally distributed between rotating and linearly oscillating modes. How can that be since angular momentum is conserved and linear momentum is conserved?

Answer (score 1):

The equipartition theorem assumes you have a large number of molecules interacting with each other. Collisions between molecules can redistribute energy between translational, rotational and vibrational modes. The equipartition theorem tells you that at equilibrium energy will be distributed between the various modes in accordance with a Boltzmann distribution.

Angular momentum can by transferred into and out of rotational modes when two molecule collide and either the incoming or outgoing or both collisions are not colinear (which is of course generally the case).